Why is LM339 producing digital signal at input?
I am testing the following schematic on a breadboard, where CMP1 and CMP2 are comparators on the same LM339 IC. Supply is 6V for the entire circuit.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The comparator input is taken from two stages of amplification of a PIR motion sensor. The 2nd stage output "B" should be a sine wave that oscillates around 3V. I have confirmed with a voltmeter that V+ is roughly 3V when there is nothing moving in front of the sensor and it is not connected to the input of the comparators.
However, when I connect it to the comparators like in the schematic, and measure the voltage at the non-inverting terminal of CMP1 (or the inverting terminal of CMP2), I observe that a digital signal seems to be produced. I.e., an oscilloscope shows that it is at ~5V when nothing is moving in front of the sensor. But when I moved my hand across the sensor, the trace jumps down to a lower voltage (no sinusoidal wave form, just a jump). This is what I was expecting to see at the output rather than the input terminals. Why might this be happening?
The unused inputs of the LM339 comparator are tied to ground with 10K resistors.
Edit: having had another session on the oscilloscope, I realize that the information on the original post is wrong. In fact, V+ (the output from OA2) is not 3V when there is nothing moving in front of the sensor and it is not connected to the input of the comparators. It is roughly ~4.75V. And this is the exact same when it is connected to the input of the comparator. I had the oscilloscope on DC setting, which explains the square wave form. When changing the oscilloscope to AC setting, and increasing the V/div, I can see that in fact it is a sinusoidal wave that looks like this:

presumably because it hits the upper threshold of amplification set by the supply rail? My apologies to all who answered and commented under the false information in the original post. By using a separate resistor string with 33K and 22K resistors to bias the second stage of amplification with its mid-point, the output from OA2 seemed to oscillate around 2.75V (not the expected 2.4V). So the problem is with the biasing of OA2, not the comparator. Be aware that I have been drawing upon the concepts and schematics from these application notes for this project, as well as these design notes for the IRA S210 sensor.

Also be aware of the common mode input voltage ranges when you connect your sensor. Make sure that the 3V plus the sinusoidal don't exceed the common mode range.

Scope image needed.

The schematics cannot resemble what you built, as in the schematics there are two separate comparators. So we don't know what you built and is it built correctly or not.

The connections between LM324 and the LM339 make no sense. Its not the input of LM339 that is causing anything, it's the whole circuit making the LM324 output to oscillate, the positive input of LM324  is floating, you don't connect grounds on the two circuits. Or if you do, you did not draw them. The power supply connections are also unknown. As drawn, there is no way it works. Draw each and every connection between everything.

@Justme It looks to me like the schematic is correct, but the physical build probably isn't. The second LM324's non-inverting input is using the comparator reference divider string, as a perhaps premature "optimization". The original circuit used a similar divider - see my answer.

@Tyassin The 3V common mode is unnecessarily high but the op-amps will still work. It should be at (6-1.5)/2 = 4.5/2 = 2.25V. The original amplifier was powered from 5V and it has the common mode set to 2.4V. Also a wee bit high.


The circuit's gain is way, way too high. The total gain is around 40k times. Only a 1/10th of that is needed.

Even with "just" 4000x gain, the amplifier is very sensitive to feedback from heavy loads - e.g. comparators and their outputs - to the input, via power supply rails.

It doesn't help that you've shared the reference voltage divider between the op-amps and the comparators. This is a likely source of inadvertent feedback, since the comparator inputs don't have a constant input current. It varies a bit with voltage, and also with their output state and supply voltage.


I would set up the voltage reference for the amplifier 2nd stage and for the comparators as follows:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This lets you switch between the reference source local to OA2, as well as the one shared with the comparators.
You should also perform the following sanity check:

Set up the divider as above.

Disconnect the window comparator from the output of the amplifier.

Feed a 1Hz 1Vpp + 2.4VDC sine wave from a generator into the input of the comparators that you just disconnected in step 2. Check two things:

That the output of the comparators is flipping back and forth as expected.

That the output of the amplifier 2nd stage is rock solid. If it isn't, there's feedback from the comparator output load, via capacitive feedback and/or power supply rails, to the amplifier supplies.





This circuit, even at 4000x gain, will be very sensitive to inadvertent positive feedback, and to external noise. On a solderless breadboard you need a ground plane. On a protoboard things have to be close together, and there still needs to be a shield around the sensor and the 1st amplifier stage connections.
See how I had to assemble a high gain optical detector on a breadboard. Note the separation of the transmitter and the receiver, and the ground plane:

I've also assembled it more permanently on a single protoboard. Note the shielding needed to make the receiver insensitive to interference from other nearby circuits/devices that may be in the enclosure:

For more details, see this question.

The unused op-amps and comparators you are using should be connected as below. That's specific to the types you're using, not any sort of a general recommendation.

Using the series resistors for the comparators, as you have done, is not a problem, but also unnecessary. Wires take less room on the breadboard.

Hi. How does LM324 have positive feedback in the original circuit?

A possible feedback exists from the comparator, via supply rails or reference divider, into the non-inverting input of the 2nd stage LM324. Given generally poor quality of solderless breadboard builds by novices, the nice schematics don't represent the actual circuit with various parasitic series impedances in the supply rails, local feedbacks via supply pins, and capacitive coupling between stages.

Have updated the question with further information after using an oscilloscope again

Here is what you can see if a generator is used as input.
Functions outputs are as "comparator".
Note that a Vinput "min" should be used (~ 1.5 V peak + 2.5V offset).
Trips points are around \$ 5 V/4 = 1.25 V \$ and \$ 5 V * 3/4 = 3.75 V\$.

So, if you see a "logic" input, it is the fact that "output" of the sensor is "logic" and "passes" the trip points.
Here is the AC behavior of the preamplifier ... Gain is approximately 40k.
You can see the "gain" of the two opamps.
Note that you need power supply decoupling capacitors.


I do not see how this answers the asked question. OP is seeing a square wave on the signal input.

As I explain, if the input is a "square" wave, it is the fact that the sensor is a "logical" output. The two amplifiers have a very "high" gain (628k/3k3)^2.

@Antonio51 the oscilloscope reading from the V+ node is very different when connecting it to the comparator input... When tied to ground with a 10K resistor, the trace moves upwards and downwards from it's bias voltage of 3V. But when tied to the comparator inputs, it jumps between 5V and 1V.

With a "gain" of  ~ 36 000 in the passband,  a very "little" change ( 2.5V/36000= ~ 65 uV) in the sensor will make "jumps" at outputs of opamps (between the outputs limits).
